# using cells embedded with text in calculations

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can I incorporate text within a cell while maintaining the ability to use that cell in other calculations?

For example: To show "Days" within a cell, I've used formala: =B1-A1&" "&"Days", with A1 representing the start date and B1 representing the end date. [6/29/2016-6/29/2015&" "&"Days"=366 Days]

I want to then use this value in other calculations. A simple example would be adding 1 to the cell to get 377 days. Since the cell has text, I'm getting the #VALUE! error. I believe there is a way around this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question.

Say we have a cell with the formula:

```
=B1-A1
```

Format the cell as `Custom`  **General  " Days"**

[image]

This allows the cell to display properly and still be used numerically !

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your result with Value and Left like the following:
**=VALUE(LEFT(C1,FIND(" ",C1,1)-1))**
C1 is where you have your formula =B1-A1&" "&"Days"
Find will give the number of character where you have " " space and left will return the number on the left of " "
Value will convert the result to number so you can make calculation with it